# Convert pandas dtypes to BigQuery type representation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, google-bigquery

I've just installed pandas and numpy, and don't have any experience with them. I'm trying to get a json data structure similar to what you need to pass to Google BigQuery. https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.encoding

### Goal

1. Determine data_types
2. Return `JSON` where key is the column name and value is one of the data types: `STRING, INTEGER, FLOAT, BOOLEAN, TIMESTAMP or RECORD`

### What I've tried

```
 import numpy as np                                                              
 import pandas as pd                                                             
 import config                                                                   
 import boto                                                                     
 from StringIO import StringIO                                                   

 k = boto.connect_s3(**config.AWS_PARAMS).get_bucket('xxxxxxx').get_key('DATA.csv')                                          
 o = StringIO(k.get_contents_as_string())                                             
 df = pd.read_csv(o)                                                             

 def map_dtype(dtype):                                                                                                                                 
     if dtype.kind == 'i':                                                       
         # [int8, int16, int32, int64]                                           
         return "INTEGER"                                                        
     elif dtype.kind == 'u':                                                     
         # [uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64]                                       
         return "INTEGER"                                                        
     else:                                                                       
         return "STRING"                                                         

 fields = []                                                                     
 for c, d  in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes):                                        
         field = {}                                                              
         field['type'] = map_dtype(d)                                            
         field['name'] = c                                                       
         fields.append(field)                                                    


 print fields
```

### Result

```
[{'type': 'INTEGER', 'name': 'VALUE'}, {'type': 'INTEGER', 'name': 'ID'}, {'type': 'STRING', 'name': 'Key'}, {'type': 'STRING', 'name': 'EmailAddress'}]
```

As you can see I'm getting the right result. but I don't like how I'm doing it. I feel there is an easier way to do this.

### What I want to improve

1. `map_dtype()` function, as you can see I have to manually map data types with there string representation in BigQuery
2. `For each loop`, feels like there should be an easier way to get a data_type assigned to a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that the methods in `pandas.io.gbq` will help you much here. If I understand correctly, you have a CSV file and you are attempting to map the dtypes to the BigQuery types. As far as I found when working on `pandas.io.gbq`, there's not a really convenient way to do this.

For a helpful list of numpy types see:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface

> The basic type character codes are:
>
> - t   Bit field (following integer gives the number of bits in the bit field).
> - b   Boolean (integer type where all values are only True or False)
> - i   Integer
> - u   Unsigned integer
> - f   Floating point
> - c   Complex floating point
> - O   Object (i.e. the memory contains a pointer to PyObject)
> - S   String (fixed-length sequence of char)
> - U   Unicode (fixed-length sequence of Py_UNICODE)
> - V   Other (void * – each item is a fixed-size chunk of memory)

In this case, I feel like a dictionary is your best bet for the lookups, and you can replace the `for` loop with list comprehension:

```
df = DataFrame({'a' : [1,2], 'b' : [True, False], 'c' : [1.1, 2.1], 'd' : ['a', 'b']})
type_dict = {
    'b' : 'BOOLEAN',
    'i' : 'INTEGER',
    'f' : 'FLOAT',
    'O' : 'STRING',
    'S' : 'STRING',
    'U' : 'STRING'
}
[{'name' : col_name, 'type' : type_dict.get(col_type.kind, 'STRING')} for (col_name, col_type) in df.dtypes.iteritems()]
```

Yields:

```
[{'type': 'INTEGER', 'name': 'a'}, {'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'name': 'b'}, {'type': 'FLOAT', 'name': 'c'}, {'type': 'STRING', 'name': 'd'}]
```

In this case, I explicitly reference 'O','S', and 'U' in the dict - you can handle this any number of ways. Obviously one needs to be careful with the 'O' case, as the it may not have a useful string representation. Likewise, since I use the `.get()` method, I assume that the string representation of the unsupported types is better than nothing. This may not be the case for you (or you might wish to avoid possible type casting down the road), so it might be better to directly look up the value as `type_dict[col_type]` and handle the exceptions on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 5):

Good news! Since version 0.13 pandas officially (and experimentally) supports Google BigQuery.

Check `read_gbq`, and particularly `to_gbq` (to put data into BigQuery): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#google-bigquery.

Video and links to sample notebooks here:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/1xucma/video_bigquery_python_pandas_and_r_for_data/

(thanks Pearson!)

Comment: I saw those functions, but the problem is I don't want to send data to BigQuery, I just need an output in `JSON` format, with the same data types